# Populate input fields with values when option is selected in php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a form that i would like to submit details when an option is selected from the database.

The mysql database table :-

**USERS** contains fields like [email],[age],[name].

I want to be able to populate the other input fields values when one field is selected from the menu.

```
        <form>
        User
        <select name="user" id="user">
          <option>-- Select User --</option>
          <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
          <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
          <option value="Hannah">Hannah</option>
        </select>

        <p>

          Age 
          <input type="text" name="age" id="age">

        </p>
        <p>
          Email 
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        </p>
        </form>
```

How do i acheive this using jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try this,

on your HTML page:

write this to your html page,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user').on('change',function(){
        var user = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url : "getUser.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            async : false,
            data : { user : user},
            success : function(data) {
                userData = json.parse(data);
                $('#age').val(userData.age);
                $('#email').val(userData.email);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

in getUser.php:

### getUser.php

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass","mydb");

$user = $_REQUEST['user'];    
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT age,email FROM userstable WHERE name = '".$user."' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

json_encode($row);die;
```