# Populate input with database while using select option in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have Select option which has Customer names. I want to fill phone and email fetched from database onto these 2 input fields. I am using javacript to achieve, followed @mr J answer mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662282/populate-input-fields-with-values-when-option-is-selected-in-php-mysql). I tried to `alert(user);`  I get selected value but nothing else happens.

addlead.php

```
 <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Phone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone no.">
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="form-group row">
             <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" onkeyup="checkemail();" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#customer_name').on('change',function(){
    var user = $(this).val();
    alert(user);
    $.ajax({
        url : "search2.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        async : false,
        data : { user : user},
        success : function(data) {
            userData = json.parse(data);
            $('#phone').val(userData.phone);
            $('#email').val(userData.email);
        }
    }); 
    });
    });
    </script>
```

search2.php

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user_crm", "pass", "kaem_crm");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];    
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT phone,email FROM customer WHERE Cust_name = '".$user."' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

json_encode($row);die;
```

Comment: Note that your code is susceptible to SQL injection. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when you open your browser's developer toolbar? Did you check the network tab in the toolbar to see what your PHP script is returning? Avoid `alert` as means of debugging, you can get more information and in a cleaner and more usable way if you do a `console.log` instead.

Comment: Also, drop that `async : false`, you don't need it, you want async for this case. And you don't need `userData = json.parse(data);` when you specify `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: if I remove `userData = json.parse(data);` then how would I get value which I am by`$('#phone').val(userData.phone);`

Comment: Because `dataType: 'json'` option that you set in the AJAX request tells it that it will receive JSON as response and then it automatically turns it into an object.

Comment: so I removed `datatype: 'json'` however kept `userData = json.parse(data);` , then it should be good?

Comment: Yes, that's also a possible way to do it.

Comment: @mark You have this `onkeyup="checkemail();"` in your HTML. Where and what does that function do?

Comment: thats for checking email if it exists in database, I have different function for it

Answer (score -2):

You are not returning the result, try this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user_crm", "pass", "kaem_crm");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];    
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT phone,email FROM customer WHERE Cust_name = 
'".mysqli_escape_string($con, $user)."' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

header('Content-Type: application/json'); //set the content type for browser
echo json_encode($row); //return result to browser
mysqli_close($con); //close mysql connection
```

On the form page

```
  <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="customer_name" name="name" placeholder="Select Name.">
             <option value="some value">some value</option>
           </select>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone no.">
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group row">
         <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" onkeyup="checkemail();" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#customer_name').on('change',function(){
 var user = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
    url : "search2.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    async : true,
    data : { user : user},
    success : function(data) {    
        $('#phone').val(data.phone);
        $('#email').val(data.email);
    }
}); 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Copying a bunch of unchanged code obscures the change you made. I'd suggest you remove all the code before return to make your change clearer.

Comment: You don't need that header, the AJAX is already expecting JSON because `dataType: 'json'` is set.

Comment: @mark Did you check if the query is returning any results? Also is the search2.php file on same level with your addlead.php file?

Comment: yes both files are same level. How do I check if query return any result. Table has the values

Comment: @mark Here's a thorough [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/4205384) on debugging db related problems.

Comment: @andychukse you made customer_name `input type="text"` ? however i tried but no luck

Comment: @mark I have updated the form and I mistakenly type search.php instead of search2.php. Try again, but make sure you update the select options with name that exists on your DB. Also crosscheck the database connection.

Comment: @andychukse I know this might sound novice but still, how do check if mysql query returns values?

Comment: @mark Here is a simple way to check. On the search2.php file edit $user = $_REQUEST['user']; to $user = 'some value'; replace some value with a name in the database. Then run the search2.php file in your browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211075/discussion-between-andychukse-and-mark).